# multiple assignments with a comma in python

Tags: python

I tried to find an explanation of [this](http://docs.quantifiedcode.com/python-anti-patterns/readability/not_using_unpacking_for_updating_multiple_values_at_once.html), the Gotcha part:

```
b = "1984"
a = b, c = "AB"
print(a, b, c)
```

returns:

```
('AB', 'A', 'B')
```

I understand what happens with multiple equals:

```
a = b = 1
```

but using it together with a comma, I cannot understand the behaviour, ideas in why it works that way?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answer is

```
a = b, c ="AB"
```

acts like:

```
a = (b, c) = "AB"
```

This is why:

```
a = "AB" and b = "A" and c = "B"
```

Comment: brilliant, it took me a minute to understand a = "AB" , in case someone else is wondering, is because a points to the memory where "AB" is stored, has nothing to do with the result of the second assignation

Comment: Interestingly, `a="AB"` is actually performed *before* `(b,c)="AB"` (to see this, you have to construct a situation in which assignments have side effects). This is counterintuitive to me because C/C++ would do it in the reverse order.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = b, c = "AB"
```

Is not interpreted the way you think it does. You do have a multiple assignment, but it is not a = b and c = "AB". It is c,b = "AB" and a = "AB". In python

```
x = y = z = 1
```

Is interpreted as x, y, and z getting assigned value 1. And comma is used to unpack lists of values into individual variables, so b, c = "AB" unpacks "AB" into "A" and "B". So at the end of this line,

```
a = b, c = "AB"
a == "AB" 
b == "A"
c == "B"
```

Answer (score -2):

This comes down to order of operations, line 2 is actually two different statements.

```
a = b
```

is completed first.  Then

```
b, c = "AB"
```

which is unpacking the value of "AB" and assigning "A" to b and "B" to c.

Comment: `a=b` is *not* completed first. If it were, you'd have the OP's expected behaviour and `a` would end up as `"1984"`.    `a="AB"` and `(b,c)="AB"` are the two assignments that actually happen (the order in which they're performed is not the problem in this case)

Comment: ...but `a="AB"` *is* completed first, before `b=''A"` and `c="B"`.  That is presumably what you intended to say.  And I must say, it's a surprise to me that the assignments are performed in that order - but order only matters if there are side-effects of assignment.

Comment: Don't know what I was thinking now that I read what I wrote.... not enough coffee this morning.

Comment: a side effect of your insufficient caffeination was that it made me want to check out which order Python actually performs the assignments, and I'm happy to have learned something new from that.